# Why print statement produces a newline without any tags in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's the code -

```
import os

file = open("list.txt", "rw+")
text = file.readline()
print "ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i \""+text+"\" -vf scale=1280:720 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 \""+text+".mp4\""

os.system("ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i \""+text+"\" -vf scale=1280:720 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 \""+text+".mp4\"")
```

But the output is like this :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i "some-file-path
" -vf scale=1280:720 -shortest -acodec copy -vcodec mpeg4 "some-file-path"
```

Whereas it should be in a single line

And ffmpeg throws an error that file doesn't exist !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your file has a new line character (`'\n'`) in the end of the line,
so `text` is `"some-file-path\n"`.

You should change `text = file.readline()` to `text = file.readline().strip()`.

Comment: or `file.readline().rstrip()` if you don't want to strip away leading whitespace / indentation.

Answer (score -2):

ALl lines in textfiles (when python reads them at least) end in "\n"

easy solution

```
text = file.readline()[:-1]
```

this will trim the last character "\n" from the line. 
careful when doing this, since if you want to write the line back, you need to append a "\n" to it (when useing file.write("something"))

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: It often does. Most text editors will insert a newline as the last character in a file. But there's no requirement that it exists.

Comment: even if you guys are right, my solution is still correct since you can easily add an if statement to check if the "\n" is there before you delete it.